# DocViewProperty XML Serialization

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr, aem, sling

DocViewProperty#format can be used to serialize a Java string to the JCR docview XML format. However, the output of that method still appears to respect carriage-return/line-feed rather than using a hex escaped control char. This means that even after I use DocViewProperty#format, I won't necessarily get the same String as what may show up in a .content.xml file in a CQ5 package -- where that whitespace is escaped. What in the serialization mechanism performs that work and how can I use that rather than rolling up a close approximation of it on my own?